# Convert web results to PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I believe this is probably simple and has been asked before but i could not find it.. I have tried searching for the key or the value but i cannot get it figured out

`$priceComp_xml":[{"CurrencyCode":"USD","Amount":"92.35"}]` is the return from website

i have tried
$array1 = json_decode($priceComp_xml,TRUE); did not put it into an array
i have also tried but i cant get it into an array so that i can get the value

```
array_values() 
array_key_exists() 
array_search()
```

and i would like to put 92.35 into a php variable $cost

Comment: What do you mean by "the return from the website"? Is that string the result of an API call? What you showed there won't work with json_decode because it isn't JSON. there are parts of it that are JSON, but the string as a whole is not.

Comment: what happens when you `var_dump($array1)`?

Comment: Just making sure I understood correctly - are you literally getting back `$priceComp_xml":[{"CurrencyCode":"USD","Amount":"92.35"}]` from the website? Or is the `$priceComp_xml":` part of your code?

Comment: So, adding to @Don't Panics commebt, if $priceComp_xml is not part of the string, then it's just a json array, you need access each element and then json_decide it.

Comment: sorry the $priceComp_xml is part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is really your result and you always have `$priceComp_xml:` in front, you could simply skip the first 16 chars and then use `json_decode`

```
$res = '$priceComp_xml":[{"CurrencyCode":"USD","Amount":"92.35"}]';
$json = substr($res, 16);
$data = json_decode($json);
```

If the prefix has sometimes other names, you could still skip everything till the first occurance of the `:`-char.

```
$res = '$priceComp_xml":[{"CurrencyCode":"USD","Amount":"92.35"}]';
$json = substr($res, strpos($res, ':') + 1);
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: still returns [{"CurrencyCode":"USD","Amount":"92.35"}] i need to get the value of Amount 92.35 into a variable

Comment: @ForgivenIT `$data` contains the json object representation of your return value - if you just want the amount, you have to use `$data[0]->Amount`

Comment: after doing a varialbe dump i see    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#1569 (2) {
    ["CurrencyCode"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
    ["Amount"]=>
    string(5) "92.35"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to remove the leading variable name.
Using explode means that it will work even if the variable name changes.

I use explode on `":` and limit it to two items.

```
$str = '$priceComp_xml":[{"CurrencyCode":"USD","Amount":"92.35"}]';

$arr = json_decode(explode('":', $str,2)[1], true);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["CurrencyCode"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
    ["Amount"]=>
    string(5) "92.35"
  }
}
```

And to get the amount you can use

```
echo $arr[0]['Amount']; //92.35
```

https://3v4l.org/Vcpov

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#1569 (2) {
    ["CurrencyCode"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
    ["Amount"]=>
    string(5) "92.35"
  }
}  

This is what I get from var_dump  
echo $arr[0]['Amount']; is null

Comment: @ForgivenIT I thought the second argument of json_decode is array/object. If you used my code it should return an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove unwanted `string` using `str_replace` and `json_decode` result

```
$arr = json_decode(str_replace('$priceComp_xml":' , "" , $response ) , true );
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I finally got it (i was not noticing the SimpleXMLElement until i did a var_dump

```
$count = $compPricing[0];
$result=array();
        foreach($count as $number){
            $Amount=$count->Amount->__toString();
            $CurrencyCode=$count->CurrencyCode->__toString();

        $result = array('Amount' => $Amount, 'CurrencyCode' => $CurrencyCode);
}
echo json_encode($Amount);
```